# get the data from a jlist vector to pop up in a message box in Java

Tags: java, vector, jlist, messagebox

does anyone knows how to create a message box when the user closes the java application. the content inside the message box will show the food order list which the customer order, it will get the order from the vector inside the jlist from the datastorage.

```
public void getAllOrder(Order o)
{
    this.confirmorderlist.add(o);
    for(int i=0; i<confirmorderlist.size(); i++)
    {
        Order order=confirmorderlist.get(i);
        Product[] OrderArr=order.getOrder();

        for(int k=0; k<OrderArr.length; k++)
        {

            String msg="Your order is ";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg +OrderArr[k].getProductName() +" x" +OrderArr[k].getQuantity(), "ORDER", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would want to create a JFrame with EXIT_ON_CLOSE set as the default close operation as the last step and close all of the other frames.  If you actually close the Java application, it erases all of the associated windows.